# How to update tableView cells?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView and I want update it every 10 seconds. For it I do:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "reloadTable", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func reloadTable() {
    print("reload")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

but it doesn't reload correctly. What it means:

Yes, it reloads, but my data doesn't update, but when I drag my tableView to top and leave it, my tableView cells' data **update**. How can I achieve this effect programmatically?

**UPDATE**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> onlineUserCell {
    let cell:onlineUserCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! onlineUserCell

    let user = OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)

    cell.username.text = user.displayName

    if user.unreadMessages.intValue > 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = .orangeColor()
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    }
    configurePhotoForCell(cell, user: user)

    cell.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarImage.frame.size.height / 2
    cell.avatarImage.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.table.reloadData()
}` try this

Comment: How you are constructing cell? Share the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: I see. Try what @HarvantS. has suggested. Probably it is because of a thread other than UI thread. Keep a break point in your method and see if you are getting the update object of `user` when you are updating it.

Comment: @HarvantS. it doesn't work =/ the same result. It reloads just when I drag to top my tableView

Comment: @Gandalf his method doesn't work, too =/

Comment: @Orkhan Have you tried debugging it. Make sure you get the updated object of `user` when you update table with timer firing. Your code seems ok as long as datasource is updated correctly.

Comment: @Gandalf can we continue in chat? I want to share another info with you, my function which sets data to cells. I cannot create a chat =/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91344/discussion-between-orkhan-and-gandalf).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but if the table isn't visually updating, you probably aren't calling the UI code on the main thread. All UI code needs to be executed on the main thread in iOS.

Look up dispatch_async and/or performSelectorOnMainThread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your datasource programmatically too.The reloadData() method just refresh the cell.If you don't refresh the datasource(the actually array) there is noting different.

Comment: OP has mentioned that when he drags tableview it updates properly. So i guess nothing wrong with datasource update.